# I am going through EJS tutorial and confused about where exactly to open and close <% and %>?

Tags: javascript, ejs

Why is the code below correct :

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i<=movies.length; i++){ %>
    <li><%= movies[i] %></li>
    <%}%>   
</ul>
```

and why is this not?

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i<=movies.length; i++){ 
    <li><%= movies[i] %></li>
    }%> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<li>` and `</li>` are *raw HTML* that you want to output. They aren't JS code. They need to be *outside* the EJS tags.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= %>` used to print data. `<% %>` used to process  such as for loop, while loop, if condition, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin said, `<li>` tag need to be outside of the EJS tags. One tip, to iterate list in EJS, the easy way is to use `forEach`:

```
<ul>
    <% movies.forEach(function(movie) { %>
    <li><%= movie %></li>
    <%});%>   
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

EJS is translated to actual JavaScript code. You can imagine the bits between the `<% %>` brackets to be literal JavaScript code that will be used verbatim and the bits outside as strings that will be printed.

For example, the template you've given would translate to something like the following:

```
var output = '';
output += '<ul>\n    ';
for(var i=0; i<=movies.length; i++){
output += ' \n    <li>';
output += String(movies[i]);
output += '</li>\n    ';
}
output += '\n</ul>';
return output;
```

Notice how `<%= %>` is different in that it will be replaced with the actual string value of the expression, not just used verbatim. Also notice how all the spaces and line breaks outside the `<% %>` bits are preserved as part of the string values -- these will appear in the output of the template, unlike those inside the `<% %>` and `<%= %>` bits.

In other words:

1. By default, everything is one big string.
2. The `<% %>` pair  says "string ends here, JavaScript code follows" and then "JavaScript code ends here, another string follows".
3. The `<%= %>` pair says "string ends here, a JavaScript expression that should be added to the string follows" and then "JavaScript expression ends here, another string follows".

For completeness, here's what your "wrong" example would look like:

```
var output = '';
output += '<ul>\n';
for(var i=0; i<=movies.length; i++){ 
    <li><%= movies[i] %></li>
}
output += '\n</ul>';
return output;
```

Note how this has the `<li>` and `</li>` in the JavaScript code instead of in the strings, which is not valid JavaScript syntax. Even worse: the `<%= movies[i] %>` bit in between is ALSO in the JavaScript code because it's only recognized by the template language when it occurs inside the string part, not the JS parts.